# How to reshape csv file into matrix form for Digit Recognition Machine Learning

Tags: python, csv, data-science, mnist, kaggle

so I am new in machine learning, and I try to work on Digit Recognizer on Kaggle...

so I already load the csv file with

```
train_df=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
```

and the result is

```
label,pixel0,pixel1,pixel2,pixel3,...,pixel783
4, 0 ,0 ,0 ,10 ,...,0
```

I know that i need to reshape it into matrix form 28 x 28, but I don't know how to reshape and print the image...

Could anyone teach me how to reshape and print the image? I really appreciate your help.. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example for you with generated random images:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

arr = np.random.randint(2,size=(1000,784))
train_df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

mat28x28 = train_df.values.reshape((train_df.shape[0],28,28))

for index in range(0,8):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, index + 1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(mat28x28[index], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.title('Image: %i' % index)
```